# How to run multiple MongoDBs with different ports within docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, multiple-instances

I am trying to run two MongoDBs within one docker-compose. As I want to store different data in each of the databases, I need to distinguish them by different ports. If I run the following docker-compose, everything works fine for port 27017, but I cannot access port 27018. In the console everything looks the same for both services, only the following log is missing for the service on port 27018:

NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
(shows up for port 27017)

When I try to access both services in the browser, the one on port 27017 works and the one on 27018 doesn't.

I'm a very glad if anybody can help me out with that issue. Working on it since pretty long. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mvertes/alpine-mongo:4.0.1-0
    volumes:
    - mongoDBvolume:/data/db
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"

   testmongo:
    image: mvertes/alpine-mongo:4.0.1-0
    command: mongod --port 27018
    volumes:
    - mongoDBvolume:/data/testdb
    ports:
    - "27018:27017"

volumes:
  mongoDBvolume:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 5):

Just remove     `command: mongod --port 27018`, so it will be on port 27017 inside the container.

The flow is like:

Host 27018 <--> docker bridge 27018:27017 <--> mongo container 27017

Comment: for some reason this does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongo:
    image : mongo
    container_name: mongo
    networks:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - "${MONGO_PORT}:27027"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: "mongod --bind_ip_all --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf"
    volumes:
      - "./data:/data/db"
      - "./mongo:/etc/mongo"

networks:
  mongo:
    driver: bridge
```

`mongod.conf` file :

```
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27027
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```